# Permissions issue calling bash script from c++ code that apache is running

Tags: c++, apache, bash, shell, centos6

The goal of this code is to create a stack trace whenever a sigterm/sigint/sigsegv/etc is caught. In order to not rely on memory management inside of the C++ code in the case of a sigsegv, I have decided to  write a bash script that will receive the PID and memory addresses in the trace array.
The Sig events are being caught.

Below is where I generate the call to the bash script

```
trace_size = backtrace(trace, 16);
trace[1] = (void *)ctx->rsi;
messages = backtrace_symbols(trace, trace_size);

char syscom[356] = {0};
sprintf(syscom,"bash_crash_supp.sh %d", getpid());
for (i=1; i<(trace_size-1) && i < 10; ++i)
{
    sprintf(syscom,"%s %p",syscom,trace[i]);
}
```

Below is where my issue arises. The command in syscom is generating correctly. I can stop the code before the following popen, run the command in a terminal, and it functions correctly.
However running the script directly from the c++ code does not seem to work.

```
setuid(0);
FILE *bashCommand = popen(syscom,"r");

char buf[256] = {0};
while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),bashCommand) != 0) {
    LogMessage(LOG_WARNING, "%s\n", buf);
}
pclose(bashCommand);
exit(sig);
```

The purpose of the bash script is to get the offset from /proc/*pid*/maps, and then use that to run addr2line to get the file name/line number.

```
strResult=$(sudo cat /proc/"$1"/maps | grep "target_file" | grep -m 1 '[0-9a-fA-F]')

offset=$( cut -d '-' -f 1 <<< "$strResult");
```

However offset is getting 0 when I run from the c++ code, but when I run the exact same command (that is stored in syscom in the c++ code) in a terminal, I get the expected output.

I have been trying to fix this for a while. Permissions are most likely the issue, but I've tried to work around these with every way I know of/have seen via google. The user trying to run the script (currently running the c++ code) is apache.

The fix does not need to worry about the security of the box. If something as simple as "chmod 777 /proc -r" worked, that would have been the solution (sadly the OS doesn't let me mess do such commands with /proc).

Things I've already tried:

- Adding `` around the command that's stored in syscom from the c++ code
- chown the script to apache
- chmod 4755 on the bash_crash_supp.sh script, allowing it to always fire as root.
- I have added apache to sudoers (visudo), allowing them to run sudo without using a password
- I have added a sub file to sudoers.d (just in case) that does the same as above
- I have looked into objdump, however it does not give me either the offset or the file/line num for an addr (from what I can see)
- I have setuid(0) in the c++ code to set the current user to root

Command generated in C++ 
bash_crash_supp.sh 25817 0x7f4bfe600ec8 0x7f4bf28f7400 0x7f4bf28f83c6 0x7f4bf2904f02 0x7f4bfdf0fbb0 0x7f4bfdf1346e 0x7f4bfdf1eb30 0x7f4bfdf1b9a8 0x7f4bfdf176b8

Params in bash: 
 
25817 0x7f4bfe600ec8 0x7f4bf28f7400 0x7f4bf28f83c6 0x7f4bf2904f02 0x7f4bfdf0fbb0 0x7f4bfdf1346e 0x7f4bfdf1eb30 0x7f4bfdf1b9a8 0x7f4bfdf176b8

Can anyone think of any other ways to solve this?

Comment: 1) What's your shabang (the line starting `#!`) in the `bash_crash_supp.sh` script and 2) include an `echo "$*"` in the shell script and post the results.

Comment: #!/bin/bash is the shabang at the top. Added the echo of the params, as well as the command that's being generated from the c++ code

Comment: What does `strResult` contain?  Could you do an `echo "${strResult}"` and post it?  Trying to narrow down if the issue is running bad commands or getting bad output.

Comment: strResult contains nothing, this is why I think it's a permissions issue, if I run the strResult=$(sudo ...) command in a terminal as my user (not as apache) it works.

Comment: Ok, spitballing time.  Include a `whoami` near the beginning of the script to verify it runs as root.  Try `strResult=$(sudo cat /proc/"$1"/maps 2>&1)` then immediately `echo $?` to check the return code, then `echo "${strResult}"` to see if you captured any STDERR output.

Comment: Hmm... It looks like the script is still running as apache, even though I have it chmod 4755 and a setuid(0) in the c++ code

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, almost all Unix-based systems ignore `setuid` on any interpreted script (anything with a shebang `#!`) as a security precaution.

You may use `setuid` on actual executables, but not the shell scripts themselves.  If you're willing to take a *massive* security risk, you can make a wrapper *executable* to run the shell script and give the executable `setuid`.

For more information, see this question on the Unix StackExchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910